# use system properties proxy settings for camel http4

Tags: spring, http, proxy, apache-camel, system-properties

I'm trying to use the System Properties' proxy settings for the http4 component to no avail.

The [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html#HTTP4-UsingproxysettingsoutsideofURI) gives this example:

```
<camelContext>
    <properties>
        <property key="http.proxyHost" value="172.168.18.9"/>
        <property key="http.proxyPort" value="8080"/>
    </properties>
</camelContext>
```

but that's just using hardcoded values.

Is there a way to use placeholders within the camelContext properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need the [PropertiesComponent](https://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html) to resolve properties within the `<camelContext>`:

```
<bean id="propertiesComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent" />
```

You don't need to specify a location, if you just need support for one of the following:

- [EnvPropertiesFunction](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/properties/EnvPropertiesFunction.html)
- [SysPropertiesFunction](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/properties/SysPropertiesFunction.html)
- [ServicePropertiesFunction](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/properties/ServicePropertiesFunction.html)

Now you can use placeholders in the camelContext properties:

```
<camelContext>
    <properties>
        <property key="http.proxyHost" value="{{http.proxyHost}}"/>
        <property key="http.proxyPort" value="{{http.proxyPort}}"/>
    </properties>
</camelContext>
```

One other thing to note is that this will fail if the system property is not set. You can (and probably should) specify a default value after a colon

```
<property key="http.proxyHost" value="{{http.proxyHost:}}"/>
<property key="http.proxyPort" value="{{http.proxyPort:}}"/>
```

to assure it works in both cases.